# how to parse json for unknown keys in python

Tags: rest, flask-restful

I am using python flask framework to handle rest API calls. rest call with query string will be stored in JSON format with following code.now arguments in a query string are dynamic according to various filters, how can we parse this array dynamically when all keys are not known?

```
@app.route("/results")
def resultsInfo():
    if request.method == 'GET':
    # copy app arguments 
    data= request.args.copy()
```

Comment: what do you want to do to it? Since its already a dictionary, you don't need to parse it any further.

Comment: these values and keys will be used to filter JSON data

Answer (score 1):

Json object will be converted dictionary in python, so if json data is unknown, you can get keys and values by dictionary methods.

```
body = request.get_json() # returns a dictionary
for key, value in body.items():
    print(key, ' ', value) # this is how to see the all keys and values in dictionary(json sent by client)
```